# returning string from vlookup in excel

Tags: string, microsoft-excel, vlookup

I am having trouble with the `vlookup` function in excel.

I have 2 files: *file1.xlsx* and *file2.xlsx*. Both files have a list of products with a number of various information and I need to add values from *file2* to products in *file1* (paired based on the product name).

I have tried the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, [file2.xlsx]Tovar!$A:$AR,38,FALSE)
```

but keep getting a value error.

The first value is the name of the product in file1, second value is the `filename` of file2, name of the sheet and the range which should be used for lookup and the third value is the number of the column from which data should be returned.

Is there something obvious that I am overlooking please? The value to be returned is a string.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` only returns a `#VALUE!` error when the third argument is negative - which is not the case here. Any chance your formula is more complex, e.g. you multiply the result of VLOOUP with a factor or so? In this case it might be that VLOOKUP returns a text?!

Comment: What if you increase the `AR` to `AS`?

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I have increased the range to AS, this unfortunately did not help.
The exact returned value is #N/A - Value not available error.

Comment: VLOOKUP will also return a #VALUE error if the cell it returns contains a #VALUE error. Have you manually checked the cell it is looking at?

Comment: I have tried it on all the rows, hasn't worked with either. Now I actually tried the formula on a different set of files and it works. But does not work where I need it to.

Answer (score 1):

If the error your are getting is #N/A then it could be that the two columns you are comparing contain different data type, i.e. text and a number. Try one of the following:

```
=VLOOKUP(TEXT(B2, "0"), [file2.xlsx]Tovar!$A:$AR,38,FALSE)

=VLOOKUP(VALUE(B2), [file2.xlsx]Tovar!$A:$AR,38,FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for all the advice, I simply recreated both files, wrote the function again, set all the values to text by default and it started working.
I apologise for bothering you with this.